# Putting ImageView close to the TextView

Tags: java, android

My problem is that when I try always put ImageView in the same layout as the TextView and when SetText(); writes text to the textview, ImageView goes outside the layout. Yeah, I know I could put the Image to the background, but my Image is set by the setImageResource and I cannot change it or the project goes down...

So here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="onhar.personalhealth.Main"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/tip"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="260dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks alot for someone who answers this!

Comment: why are you giving hardcoded width to textView.Change it to wrap_content and try.

Answer (score 1):

Use layout_weight attribute:

```
     <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/tip"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" />


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [**android:layout_weight**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html)

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="onhar.personalhealth.Main"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/tip"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="260dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

add this line into your textview. That will add image left side of your `TextView`   `android:drawableLeft="@drawable/YOUR_IMAGE"`

Here is full xml:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/YOUR_IMAGE"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="24dip"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're using fixed widths for both views. So, you can use `FrameLayout` to keep them close together. In this way whenever the `TextView` overflows it will go beneath the `ImageView`.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="560dp"
    android:layout_height="...">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="..."
        android:layout_gravity="left"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="..."
        android:layout_gravity="right"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Another option is using dynamic width for the `ImageView`. In this way the `ImageView` will be resized based on remaining space in that `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

For responsive UI you must use relative layout, it will scale and look the same in all device this is how you could achieve this.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tip"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView2"
    android:text="some \n really \n realllllyyyyy \n \n long  \n text a \n who \n just  \n do not \n\n\n\ fit "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="260dp"
    android:layout_height="260dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

**Result**

Irrespective of length of text your image will always going to be on right side with size 260dp & your  text will scale depending on width of device screen and nothing will go out of screen.

[image]